# Verifying type of data

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to verify the type of data in `output.txt`.

example:

```
52   40.5  60  yes
30.3 20   40   no
```

result:

```
52 is Integer
40.5 is Decimal
60 is Integer
Yes is Character
```

What should be better to choose for this task - `bash` or `awk`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    types["Integer"] = "^[[:digit:]]+$"; 
    types["Decimal"] = "^[[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+$"; 
    types["Character"] = "^[[:alpha:]]+$"
} 
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        found = 0;
        for (type in types) {
            if ($i ~ types[type]) {
                print $i, "is", type;
                found = 1
            } 
        }
        if (! found) {
            print "Type not found for:", $i
        }
    }
    printf "\n"
}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

using [bash patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

```
shopt -s extglob
while read line; do
  set -- $line
  for word; do
    case $word in
      ?([-+])+([[:digit:]]) ) echo "$word is an integer" ;;
      ?([-+])@(*([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]])|+([[:digit:]]).*([[:digit:]])) ) echo "$word is a decimal" ;;
      +([[:alpha:]]) ) echo "$word is alphabetical" ;;
      *) echo "$word is a mixed string" ;;
    esac
  done
done < output.txt
```

Comment: +1 for recognizing that numbers have a leading sign, unlike the others.

Answer (score 1):

using bash, you can try something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r; do
    for token in $REPLY; do                    # no quotes here!
        if [[ "$token" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]
        then printf -- "%d is digit\n" "$token"
        elif [[ "$token" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+$ ]]
        then printf -- "%f is float\n" "$token"
        elif [[ "$token" =~ ^[[:alpha:]]+$ ]]
        then printf -- "%s is string\n" "$token"
        else printf -- "unknown class: %s\n" "$token"
        fi
    done
done < file.txt
```

- read a line (`while read` from `file.txt`, line is in var `REPLY`)
- split in tokens (`for` each token in line/`REPLY`)
- find type of current token (match complete `^..$` token with regex and classes)

Answer (score 1):

TXR: a little bit of regex, and a little bit of type system. If the token looks like a number, then let's try to convert it from string to a numeric object with `num-str`. If that fails, it must be a range error. The `typeof` function gives us the type of the object: `fixnum`, `bignum` or `float`.

```
@(freeform)
@(coll)@{token /[^\s]+/}@(end)
@(output)
@  (repeat)
@token @(if (eql (match-regex token #/[+\-]?\d+([.]\d+)?([Ee][+\-]?\d+)?/)
                 (length token))
          (let ((x (num-str token)))
            (if x (typeof x) "out-of-range"))
          "non-numeric")
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr verify.txr  -
hello world     
1.5E900 1.43 52  5A  12341234123412341234 12341234123412341234243.42 42
[Ctrl-D]
hello non-numeric
world non-numeric
1.5E900 out-of-range
1.43 float
52 fixnum
5A non-numeric
12341234123412341234 bignum
12341234123412341234243.42 float
42 fixnum
```